# How do l call this method -(int)match:(NSArray *)otherCards;

Tags: objective-c, methods, nsarray

How to l call this method from a different class because l have tried and its failing see code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Card : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *contents;

@property (nonatomic, getter = isFaceUp)BOOL faceUp;
@property (nonatomic, getter = isUnplayable)BOOL unplayable;

-(int)match:(NSArray *)otherCards;

@end


M file
#import "Card.h"

@implementation Card
@synthesize contents;

-(int)match:(NSArray *)otherCards
{
    int score = 0;
    for (Card *card in otherCards) {
        [card.contents isEqualToString:self.contents];
        score =1;
    }
    return score;
}
@end
```

l have tried this and its not working

```
  Card *card = [[Card alloc]init];
  [card match:otherCards]

  code completion is giving me this

   [card match:(NSArray *)]
```

if i replace (NSArray *) with otherCards it does'nt even pick it up l get this error

use of undeclared identifier 'otherCards'

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?

Comment: how exactly is it not working?

Comment: Please see my edit at the bottom

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  Have Xcode automatically create an array and plug it into that function?

Comment: TBlue you don't have to be a dick about it mavusane's just learning give them a break..

Comment: @Skyler: The appropriate action when you want help is to clearly and completely describe your situation, not ask someone to read your mind. "What did you expect to happen?" is information that is glaringly absent from this post. Further, this isn't a tutorial website; "just learning" isn't an excuse for slapping down some code and expecting to be led by the hand.

Answer (score 2):

You must have a variable named `otherCards` in scope, and it must have the type `NSArray` (or a subclass thereof). The variable can be

- A local variable
- A global variable
- A method parameter
- An instance variable

It's quite simple, actually :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke `match:` on the instance of `Card`, the method expects an `NSArray *` to be passed in as a parameter. Make sure that the object `otherCards` is an `NSArray *` by Option-Clicking on `otherCards`. If you only want to pass in one card, you still need to pass in an `NSArray *`.

To match one card:

```
Card *otherCard1 = [[Card alloc] init];
[card match: @[otherCard1]];
```

To match multiple cards:

```
Card *otherCard1 = [[Card alloc] init];
Card *otherCard2 = [[Card alloc] init];
Card *otherCard3 = [[Card alloc] init];
[card match: @[otherCard1, otherCard2, otherCard3]];
```

Also, I think there might be a logic issue when you say `score =1;`. Wouldn't you want an increasing score, for every card found that matches? Perhaps:

```
score +=1;
```

So the score is free to increase when the number of objects in the `NSArray * otherCards` increases.

Comment: Thanks for the help Skyler, just a learning phase appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark this one as Answered.